# How to call a function on an object between a string?

Tags: javascript, function, dom

I am attempting to put together the date and time to a specific format:

> 25  Dec  2011  12:35

I have the following sample code to start with and my task is to modify it to the above format. I am attempting to do so by putting the entire string on one line of code as shown on the 2nd fiddle below. My thought is that in between each string where i call the function on the object the function will be evaluated.

My console shows the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string index.html:19 Uncaught
>   ReferenceError: telltime is not defined(anonymous function) @
>   index.html:19

I assume it is the way I am using my strings.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Current Date and Time</title>
 <style>
  p {font: 14px normal arial, verdana, helvetica;}
 </style>
 <script>
  function telltime() {
   var out = "";
   var now = new Date();
   out += "<br />Date: " + now.getDate();
   out += "<br />Month: " + now.getMonth();
   out += "<br />Year: " + now.getFullYear();
   out += "<br />Hours: " + now.getHours();
   out += "<br />Minutes: " + now.getMinutes();
   out += "<br />Seconds: " + now.getSeconds();
   document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = out;
  }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 The current date and time are:<br/>
 <div id="div1"></div>
 <script>
  telltime();
 </script>
 <input type="button" onclick="location.reload()" value="Refresh" />
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Current Date and Time</title>
 <style>
  p {font: 14px normal arial, verdana, helvetica;}
 </style>
 <script>
  function telltime() {
   var out = "";
   var now = new Date();
   out += "<br />Date: " + now.getDate() " " + now.getMonth() + " " + now.getFullYear() + " " + now.getHours() + ":" + now.getMinutes();
   document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = out;
  }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <script>
  telltime();
 </script>
 The current date and time is:<br/>
 <div id="div1"></div>
 <input type="button" onclick="location.reload()" value="Refresh" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: typo: `now.getDate() " "` should be `now.getDate() + " "`

Comment: You are missing `+` after now.getDate()

Comment: Once that's fixed, your other problem will be that you're calling `telltime()` before you've actually created the `div` that it references. Move that `script` tag to the end of the `body` tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you missed a `+` sign here:

`[...] out += "<br />Date: " + now.getDate() <HERE> " " + [...]`

Also, there is another error, as mentioned in the comments by Paul Raub and others.
You need to move `telltime` call to after the creation of the `div` it references.
I like to put scripts like this after the body tag for a couple of reasons, one being not needing to use `document ready` functions. There are additional benefits too. You can read more in [this](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2010/04/07/high-performance-javascript-sample-chapter/) book

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Current Date and Time</title>
 <style>
  p {font: 14px normal arial, verdana, helvetica;}
 </style>
 <script>
  function telltime() {
   var out = "";
   var now = new Date();
   out += "<br />Date: " + now.getDate() + " " + now.getMonth() + " " + now.getFullYear() + " " + now.getHours() + ":" + now.getMinutes();
   document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = out;
  }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 The current date and time is:<br/>
 <div id="div1"></div>
 <input type="button" onclick="location.reload()" value="Refresh" />
</body>

 <script>
  telltime();
 </script>

</html>
```

Comment: this not works, the code call telltime() before the dom $div1. it has error

Answer (score 2):

1: as other answers, you missed a + in you code.

2: you should call this function after the div. because the html runs from top to end. so the code should be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Current Date and Time</title>
    <style>
        p {font: 14px normal arial, verdana, helvetica;}
    </style>
    <script>
        function telltime() {
            var out = "";
            var now = new Date();
            out += "<br />Date: " + now.getDate() +" " + now.getMonth() + " " + now.getFullYear() + " " + now.getHours() + ":" + now.getMinutes();
            document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = out;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    The current date and time is:<br/>
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <input type="button" onclick="location.reload()" value="Refresh" />
    <script>
        telltime();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use http://momentjs.com/ and do this in one line if you'd like.

```
$('#div1').html(moment().format("DD MMM YYYY HH:mm"));
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm going through a book to learn JS effectively first.